# Captioning an image

Tags: html, css, markup, semantic-markup

What's the neatest way to caption images on the web using the latest in HTML/CSS? Demo code please.

Comment: I'd say the examples using tables in this link are wrong wrong wrong. Tables are supposed to be used for arranging data.

Comment: I agree with you... however the link also provides ways to format captions using pure CSS.  The table layout examples are there to provide alternative ways to do this.  I think it is a good idea to have many ways available.  I highly suggest using DIV only layouts.

Comment: This article (originally posted by @jgallant) seems to solve OP's problem: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html

Answer (score 16):

There are several semantic ways to markup an image and its caption.

### Old school way

An old school method is to use HTML definition lists, see [Image captions the semantic way](http://www.naterkane.com/blog/image-captions-the-semantic-way/). (There are other [nice tutorials](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/thumbnail_and_caption/gallery_of_thumbnails.asp) demonstrating this method.)

```
<dl>
    <dt><img src="foo.jpg" /></dt>
    <dd>Foo</dd>
</dl>
```

### Microformat

There is also a [figure microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/figure) which applies on any regular markup:

```
<div class="figure">
  <img class="image" src="foo.jpeg" alt="" /><br/>
  <small class="legend">Foo</small>
</div>
```

### HTML5

And HTML5 now provides a clean straight method for images with captions through the [`<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/).

```
<figure>
  <img src="foo.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>Foo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: That's my favorite of the many possible ways to do this.

Comment: @Torok - thanks! +1.  But "image captions the semantic way" link is dead :(

Comment: Here's the link to an [archived version of "Image captions the semantic way"](http://web.archive.org/web/20081204093254/http://www.naterkane.com/blog/image-captions-the-semantic-way/); that said, beyond the example already given above (using a <dl>), the article merely discusses how the author arrived at this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know I've seen a number of articles with some good code over at www.alistapart.com - but here's one to start you off: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit -**

Nice Example [CSS on Hover Image Captions](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-on-hover-image-captions/)

Other Examples: [Image captions on Web pages](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html)

Comment: I can already hear the CSS purists having a heart attack over this one...

Comment: Well, I guess you could argue a table holding a single image solely for the caption aspect of it is flirting with the lines of "tables for layout" - you COULD say that, I'd use this :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do

```
.img-container {position:relative;}
,img-container h4{position:absolute;bottom:0; left:0;height:Npx;line-height:20px; font-size:18px;}
.img-container img {margin-bottom:Npx;}
```

If there's a risk of the text running over more than one line you'll want to make the value of N bigger, otherwise 20px will do.

```
<div class="img-container">
<h4 class="caption">A picture of a dog</h4> //or h3, or h5 etc... - whichever is most appropriate given how you've used headings on your site
<img src,,,,>
</div>
```

Putting the caption before the image in the markup and making it a heading is I think as close as you can semantically get to saying "this is a picture of ..."

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to list all the details in a post here.

Here's a few links that discuss CSS Image Captioning in depth:

[Semi transparent image captions using CSS](http://www.cssbakery.com/2009/03/captioning-image-in-blogger.html)

[Semi transparent image captions using CSS and Javascript](http://www.cssbakery.com/2009/11/semi-transparent-image-captions-using.html)

[CSS Image Captioning with Reusable Rounded Corners](http://www.cssbakery.com/2009/03/more-on-captioning-images-reusable.html)

and finally a standalone tool that generates the CSS code necessary to caption an image:

[CSS Image Captioning Tool](http://tools.cssbakery.com/welcome/caption)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these cool image caption effects.

[Cool Image caption with CSS](http://webtips.in/image-caption-effects-css#.U14NlVWSxyI)