# Can we give captions to the images only using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, caption

I want to give captions to the images. There are two options I find.

1. By jquery
2. By only CSS

I think the second one is the cool way to go for it

I think airnb is doing it second way.

but I could not figure it out using `firebug`.

can you give me a simple example or any useful blog link for the same.

Comment: CSS is a collection of *style* rules - not for inserting content. You can hide the content of a caption div using CSS and show it on a `:hover` event if needs be. Secondly, don't do something based on coolness - do it because it's the right way for your project to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747652/captioning-an-image

Comment: http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/add-text-captions-align-images-html-css/2309/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html

Comment: "I want to give a caption to *the* images", what images? You haven't shown us anything about you, your markup, what you've tried. You expect us to answer htat?

Answer (score 1):

There's option 3) Through HTML (and CSS). Why not just add a caption in the HTML?

But to answer your question, if you want to do it in CSS, you can using something like this:

```
img {
  margin-bottom: 50px; /* Make room */
}

img:after {
  content: 'The caption of the image';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

You will still need a container for the positioning to work. And I can imagine the caption text should not actually be in CSS, so a pure CSS solution isn't ideal.